# Set specific configuration on flask unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, configuration

I have a unit test that uses values on configuration variables set on `config/default.py` - I use the same configuration variables with different values on `config/my_project/default.py` and I want to use the variables from `config/my_project/default.py` on my unit test. How can I override the configuration variables from `config/default.py` and set them on this unit test? This is what I've been trying

```
import unittest
import json


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        with open('tests/data.json') as my_json_data:
        self.json = json(load(my_json_data)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_language(self):
        with app.app_context():
            app.config['DEFAULT_LANGUAGE'] = 'en-uk'
            app.config['LOCALES'] = {
                'de-de': ['de-x', 'de-de', 'de_de', 'de'],
                'en-au': ['en-au-x', 'en-au', 'en_au', 'en'],
            }
            self.assertEqual(Helper.get_translation(self, [], 'translated_title', 'en-US', default=None), 'Plastic container')
```

Comment: Did you try something like `app.config.from_pyfile('config/my_project/default.py')`?

Comment: `app.config.from_pyfile('../config/my_project/default.py')` did the trick! Thank you Luis Orduz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `app.config.from_pyfile('config/my_project/default.py')` for loading the configuration from a file.